# External hard drive not recognised on Mac - Problem when using diskutil command on Terminal to eject it

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, external-disk, eject

I have an external Seagate hard drive that is recognised and works on Windows computers but not on my MacBook Air which I am currently using. I have looked at a lot of tutorials regarding this, and I have edited my preferences so that external disks are to be displayed on the desktop and on the sidebar.

[image]

My hard drive is not mounted on Disk Utility, but my Mac has detected and recognized its hardware information in System Information:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried resetting my Mac's NVRAM but my hard drive doesn't get recognised and I can only see its information in System Information.

I am trying to resolve this issue using Terminal. I have typed in `diskutil list` on the command line, resulting in the below:

[image]

My hard drive is disk2, and I then typed `diskutil info disk2`, to see if the system recognises the drive, as if it does it should reveal information about the drive:

[image]

I am trying to eject the drive using `diskutil eject disk2`, because after ejecting the drive, if I type the `diskutil list` command and the drive is gone from the list, I can remove it from the USB port and reconnect it and it should mount normally.

However when I type `diskutil eject disk2`, I get the following:

[image]

I am not sure why this is occurring or how to resolve this issue. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't already, please install the [Paragon Driver for macOS](https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/software/paragon/) to properly enable read and write support for NTFS on Seagate drives on your macOS. Does it work properly after installing this driver?

Comment: I have installed the software (NTFS for Mac), and my hard drive is mounted. However, it is mounted in read-only mode and I can't transfer any of my files on my Mac to it.

Comment: Where in your question do you state you wanted to write to the drive?

Comment: @ceno980 Did you restart your mac after installing the driver? If yes, and it is still not working, follow the instructions given here for [Paragon NTFS Mac Troubleshooting](https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/kb/paragon-driver-troubleshooting-006169en/#NTFS).

Comment: I have restarted my mac and I am now able to copy files to my hard drive using the driver. Thank you for your help.